# is it possible to use println as a function reference in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, method-reference

In Java 8 and 9 it is possible to have method references for printing to the console, like e.g:

```
List.of(1, 2, 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

In Kotlin I did not find a way to use a method reference to print to the console. I have tried to translate this to use a function reference:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).forEach { println(it) }
```

to:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).forEach { ::println }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io
@InlineOnly public inline fun println(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
```

How can I solve this resolution ambiguity? Is it possible to use a function reference in this case?

Comment: If Kotlin doesn’t support specifying an overload you can create a wrapper function that calls the correct overload and use that instead.

Comment: Docs link: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a function which in turn returns the function `println`, so the compiler can't figure out which `println` to return. What you want to do is use `println` itself as an argument, for which you need to use `()`:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).forEach(::println)
```